# Getting the main url with java

Tags: java, html, url, hyperlink, uri

I need to get the main url of a link, for example instead of

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

i want just 
https://stackoverflow.com/

I know you can use URI but for some reason it doesn't work well with my program so I need an alternative, I tried this with uri but as said i need another solution (maybe regex?)

```
URI uri = new URI("the url");
String domain = uri.getHost();
return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work well'?

Comment: Simply use sheme and post.That's it.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as you can do is

```
String url="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
URI uri = null;
uri = new URI(url);
String host = uri.getHost();  
System.out.println(uri.getScheme()+"://"+host+"/");
```

Result:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
```